# How to copy coordinates from a .tif that has coordinates to a .tif that does not have coordinates?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, coordinates, georeferencing, opencv

So I have done some RGB-channel extraction from a .tif file, meaning I took UAV_image.tif and I have extracted R,G,B channels on three different .tif files. Next, I did some calculations such as result = ((red^2)+(blue^2))/(blue). For all the previous operations I used mainly cv2.imwrite and tiff.imread commands. The problem is that the resulted .tif does not contains coordinates.. How can I copy the coordinates from the initial UAV_image.tif to result.tif? I tried to followed this tutorial:

> Use gdalsrsinfo to get the srs of the tiff that still has the
> projection:
>
> gdalsrsinfo -o wkt tiffwithsrs.tiff Then copy the output and use
> gdal_translate to apply it to a new tiff:
>
> gdal_translate -a_srs '...' tiffwithoutsrs.tif newfixedtif.tif just
> paste your projection after the -a_srs option

(source: [Using GDAL command line to copy projections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108673/using-gdal-command-line-to-copy-projections/108703#108703))

But the result was to copy both coordinates and colors...!!! Did I do something wrong?

Also, this guy here: ["Copy" Image coordinates to another image that is nd.array](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363902/copy-image-coordinates-to-another-image-that-is-nd-array) has a an approach that does not fit my problem, because I do not do any kind of Machine Learning training (as I see to his example - correct me If I am wrong)  and I do not use nd.array.

So, the question is how do I copy coordinates from a .tif image that has coordinates to  a .tif image that does not have coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in python using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
UAV_image = rasterio.open('UAV_image.tif')
new_tif = rasterio.open('new.tif','w',
                        driver='Gtiff',
                        height = UAV_image.height,
                        width = UAV_image.width, 
                        count = 1,
                        crs = UAV_image.crs,
                        transform = UAV_image.transform, 
                        dtype = UAV_image.dtypes)

new_tif.write(result, 1) #result from calculations
UAV_image.close()
new_tif.close()
```

This should take the geo-information from the original tif and write it to the new one.

Comment: Why do I get this error?   `File "copy_coordinates.py", line 11, in <module>
    dtype = UAV_image.dtype)
AttributeError: 'DatasetReader' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Comment: @just_learning Try with `.dtypes` , sorry spelling error. If that doesn't work you can write the datatype your new image has as a string `'uint8', 'float32'` etc.

Comment: I assumed you had some array named result as calculated in the original question. That result will then be written to this new_tif file.

Comment: One last question, which I am trying to fix for over a week...Why the end result .tif loses the number of bands, when I try this command: `img.shape`. It gives me only height, width! Shouldn't give me also `1` as the number of channels?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `img.count`https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=count#opening-a-dataset-in-writing-mode

Comment: Last question, (sorry for the many questions so far...), but what should I change in the above if I need to copy **only coordinates** from `A.tif` to `B.tif`?? In other words I do not need to store any `result`. I tried some code but it does not work and I got confused...!!

Comment: The problem is that I need to inherit the coordinates from `A.tif` (which is 4 band image) to `B.tif` (which is 3 band image). I tried configurations on count, and  the band numbers on write command, but I get errors like this guy over here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193526/rasterio-source-shape-is-inconsistent-with-given-indexes-1). I have read the tutorial: [link2](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#opening-a-dataset-in-writing-mode) without finding any solution to my problem...Any ideas/help what to do?

Comment: I'm not really sure sorry. Maybe try adding an extra empty band to the 3 band image? The solutions you linked look useful also.